# Optimising a Load Operation(To Fetch All Entities of a specific Kind) in Objectify 4

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am loading/fetching all entities of a specific kind using objectify 4 using this query:

**`ofy.load().type(Thing.class)`**

Thing is the entity, with autoGenerated Id (Long DataType), having 5-6 fields .

However, when i run this operation(assuming 1 entity to be present in datastore), it takes some time to fetch the results(like 2-4 secs). is this the normal behaviour i should expect. Or is there a way to load all entities of a specific kind faster?? 
Thank You

Comment: Are you saying there is only one entity with that type and it takes 4s? How are you measuring that ellapsed time?

Comment: @ZigMandel what i mean is. for testing purposes i have so far just saved one entity object. And when executing above operations, it seems to be time consuming. I just evaluate the time it takes for the operation to return results. Time Before executing query with Time After executing query.

Comment: but are you measuring client-side or server-side. client-side is meaningless

Comment: @ZigMandel I am measuring Server Side...Client side is obviously meaningless

Comment: @ZigMandel any thoughts on that?

Comment: Its strange that its so slow. Try a simple get by key and compare.

Comment: @ZigMandel what is the ideal time that this operation should take?..I am currently testing on development server, maybe the performance would improve.

Comment: you havent tried my previous comment, and you havent said whether what you see is on dev server or real

Comment: @ZigMandel how do i use get-by-key .i dont have an id of any entity.its autogenerated (using Long).Also i mentioned in my prev comment that i am using dev server.Thanks

Comment: Dev server perf is irrelevant.

Comment: Have you tried putting in appstats, and then doing multiple refreshes? This could be caused by startup code so make sure you're testing steady state not startup. Then see if appstats can help. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats